# Ionic Vue: How do I change the text color of a selected option?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, select, ion-select

I have a simple ionic select component with vue:

```
<template>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Select</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-select-option value="brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="blonde">Blonde</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="black">Black</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="red">Red</ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</template>

<script>
import { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption } from '@ionic/vue';

export default{
  components: { IonItem, IonLabel, IonSelect, IonSelectOption },
};
</script>
```

Once the user selected an option, I want to colour it respectively:
[image]

Unfortunatelly, the docs only reveal to me, how the colour the select option within the select dropdown ([here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select-option)).

To colour the selected option, I tried things like

```
<ion-select-option value="brown"><span style="color:brown">Brown</span></ion-select-option>
```

or

```
<ion-select-option value="brown" style="color:brown">Brown</ion-select-option>
```

How do I colour it in brown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ionic 5

You can use [CSS Shadow Parts](https://ionicframework.com/blog/customize-your-ionic-framework-app-with-css-shadow-parts/) for that.
For the `ion-select` component, the exposed parts are `icon`, `placeholder` and `text`.

```
ion-select::part(text) {
  color: brown;
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know to achieve that with earlier versions of Ionic.
It might work with latest versions of Ionic 4 though.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!